# Can someone explain the process of multi-precision multiplication in assembly?

Tags: math, assembly, multiplication

Refer to the figure below and [this link](http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH09/CH09-4.html).

[image: Figure 2.3]

Regarding Figure 2.3, I understand why M (multiplier) and N (multiplicand) are in those orders that are listed in "Partial product..M..L" that's in the rightmost column. It comes from how we were normally taught to multiply:

[image]

I understand why the figure is 64-bits long, because it's 32-bits times 32-bits.

I understand the addresses go from P~P+7 that way because the H.O. bit of the final product starts at P and L.O. bit of the final product ends at P+7.

I understand why each large rectangle is split into an upper and lower half, because the HCS12 can only handle a maximum of 16-bits times 16-bits at a time.

My problem: The way each small rectangle (lower and upper halves) are arranged is confusing me. Apparently, it's supposed to mimic the simplified multiplication process, which I can understand how is being done. I just don't understand entirely how it translates into the figure. The link from my first line also shows a similar process. I don't want to guess or assume what I think is happening. Can someone please explain in large detail (preferably steps) how you figure out which small rectangle goes into which column and row; or in other words, can you tell me how the multiplication process translates into the figure?

Comment: It's just [binomial multiplication](http://regentsprep.org/Regents/math/ALGEBRA/AV3/Smul_bin.htm) - same as you did in high school, but in binary. The split up halves of the original numbers are the to binomials you're multiplying.

Comment: Yes, regular multiplication. I just figured out what was missing: Even though it's regular multiplication, there are several ways to perform multiplication. I was taught long-hand multiplication. The method that I was supposed to be using for this problem is called partial product multiplication. In PPM, the shifts occur naturally. You can see it @ http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-9050630681203583203 As you can see, the PPM method directly translates into Figure 2.3.

Comment: I like to think of it as (H1+L1)(H2+L2) = H1H2 + H1L2 + H2L1 + L2L1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation you have is

( M<sub>H</sub><<16 +  M<sub>L</sub> ) x ( N<sub>H</sub><<16 +  N<sub>L</sub> )

with `<<` meaning "shift left by". Note that a shift left by 16 is equivalent to a multiplication by 65536, and two shifts by 16 are equivalent to one by 32.

If you multiply this out, you get

M<sub>L</sub> x N<sub>L</sub> +
M<sub>H</sub><<16 x N<sub>L</sub> +
M<sub>L</sub> x N<sub>H</sub><<16 +
M<sub>H</sub><<16 x N<sub>H</sub><<16

If you pull the shifts out:

(M<sub>L</sub> x N<sub>L</sub>) << 0 +
(M<sub>H</sub> x N<sub>L</sub>) << 16 +
(M<sub>L</sub> x N<sub>H</sub>) << 16 + 
(M<sub>H</sub> x N<sub>H</sub>) << 32

Now the shift amounts show the number of bits each block is shifted by left in the graphic.

Comment: This makes sense. It's another perspective for me, in addition to the one I just found out: partial product multiplication, which basically translates long-hand multiplication into Figure 2.3.

Comment: A minor nitpick but I think it would help readers to understand that you were able to pull the left shifts out because they are commutative (as you stated, left shifts are the same as multiplication).